# user input is not capturing the text

Tags: python, streamlit

I am trying to capture the text using text input with button called "Email" whenever i click the button instead of displaying the text the box is closing automatically

I have tried but dont know where the issue is any idea would be appreciated

```
import streamlit as st #web app and camera
import numpy as np # for image processing 
from PIL import Image #Image processing 
import cv2 #computer vision 

def dodgeV2(x, y):
    return cv2.divide(x, 255 - y, scale=256)

def pencilsketch(inp_img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(inp_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_invert = cv2.bitwise_not(img_gray)
    img_smoothing = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_invert, (21, 21),sigmaX=0, sigmaY=0)
    final_img = dodgeV2(img_gray, img_smoothing)
    return(final_img)


file_image = st.camera_input(label = "Take a pic of you to be sketched out")

if file_image:
    input_img = Image.open(file_image)
    final_sketch = pencilsketch(np.array(input_img))
    st.write("**Output Pencil Sketch**")
    st.image(final_sketch, use_column_width=True)
    if st.button("Download Sketch Images"):
        im_pil = Image.fromarray(final_sketch)
        im_pil.save('final_image.jpeg')
        st.write('Download completed')
#the issue code starts from here
        if st.button("Email"):
            form = st.form(key='my-form')
            name = form.text_input('Enter your name')
            submit = form.form_submit_button('Submit')
            st.write('Press submit to have your name printed below')
            if submit:
                st.write(f'hello {name}')
                
    
    else:
         st.write("You haven't uploaded any image file")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streamlit button has **no callbacks**. If you try to make other operations under the button, (I mean after clicking the button), the page will rerun, so you end up losing your entries.

But you can work around it by initializing a session state for the button. Also you can chose to use `st.checkbox()` if you don't want to show the **form** right away.

```py
 if st.checkbox("Click Here to Send Email"): # Modified
    form = st.form(key='my-form')
    name = form.text_input('Enter your name')
    submit_button = form.form_submit_button(label='Submit') # Modified
    st.write('Press submit to have your name printed below')
    if submit_button: # Modified
        st.write(f'hello {name}')
```

This should work fine

Comment: Is it possible to align and coloured the submit button into center @jamiu shaibu

Comment: You can ask a new question on that, elaborate how you want the button to be,  because that needs some `css` customization and you can tag me to that question, so I can see how possible it is to work around that. Thank you.

Comment: i dont know hot to tag some one in the question but as you said i have asked a new question kinly check this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73371934/how-to-center-and-coloured-the-button-in-streamlit-app

Comment: You are welcome. Its my pleasure @Nazima