# How to center and coloured the button

Tags: python, html, css, streamlit

I have an app which convert the image into pencil sketch in that app i need three changes in the buttons

1. Need to align the both buttons into center
2. Need to give some colour to the buttons
3. The both button should be in same size

Sample Code:

```
    import streamlit as st #web app and camera
    import numpy as np # for image processing 
    from PIL import Image #Image processing 

    import cv2 #computer vision 

def dodgeV2(x, y):
            return cv2.divide(x, 255 - y, scale=256)
        
def pencilsketch(inp_img):
            img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(inp_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            img_invert = cv2.bitwise_not(img_gray)
            img_smoothing = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_invert, (21, 21),sigmaX=0, sigmaY=0)
            final_img = dodgeV2(img_gray, img_smoothing)
            return(final_img)
        
def download_image(x):
    with open(x, "rb") as file:
                        btn = st.download_button(
                                label="Download image",
                                data=file,
                                file_name=x,
                                mime="image/jpg"
                            )

def email_box(x):
    if st.checkbox("Email"):
                    form = st.form(key='my-form')
                    name = form.text_input('Enter your name')
                    submit = form.form_submit_button('Send Email')
                    if submit:
                        st.write(f'x {name}')


file_image = st.camera_input(label = "Take a pic of you to be sketched out")
        
if file_image:
            input_img = Image.open(file_image)
            final_sketch = pencilsketch(np.array(input_img))
            st.write("**Output Pencil Sketch**")
            st.image(final_sketch, use_column_width=True)
            download_image("final_image.jpeg")
            email_box("hello")

else:
    st.write("You haven't uploaded any image file")
```

[image: Sample Image]

[image: Form images]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have modified the above code. Hope it helps

```
customized_button = st.markdown("""
    <style >
    .stDownloadButton, div.stButton {text-align:center}
    .stDownloadButton button, div.stButton > button:first-child {
        background-color: #ADD8E6;
        color:#000000;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }
    
    .stDownloadButton button:hover, div.stButton > button:hover {
        background-color: #ADD8E6;
        color:#000000;
    }
        }
    </style>""", unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

Comment: very nice! this question has been asked several times on the streamlit forums, but your answer is the clearest one

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** This `css` will not work for download button but will  work for the rest of the streamlit buttons. `download button` has to have a separate `css` constructed for it.

```py
import streamlit as st #web app and camera
import numpy as np # for image processing 
from PIL import Image #Image processing 

import cv2 #computer vision 

customized_button = stl.markdown("""
    <style >
    div.stButton > button:first-child {
        background-color: #578a00;
        color:#ffffff;
    }
    div.stButton > button:hover {
        background-color: #00128a;
        color:#ffffff;
        }
    </style>""", unsafe_allow_html=True)

def dodgeV2(x, y):
    return cv2.divide(x, 255 - y, scale=256)
        
def pencilsketch(inp_img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(inp_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_invert = cv2.bitwise_not(img_gray)
    img_smoothing = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_invert, (21, 21),sigmaX=0, sigmaY=0)
    final_img = dodgeV2(img_gray, img_smoothing)
    return(final_img)
        
def download_image(x):
    column1, column2, column3 = stl.columns((3, 2, 2))
        
    with columns2:
        with open(x, "rb") as file::
            btn = st.download_button(
                                label="Download image",
                                data=file,
                                file_name=x,
                                mime="image/jpg"
                            )

def email_box(x):
    if st.checkbox("Email"):
        form = st.form(key='my-form')
        name = form.text_input('Enter your name')
         
        submit_btn = customized_button  # Modified
        submit_btn = form.form_submit_button('Send Email')
        if submit_btn:
            st.write(f'x {name}')


file_image = st.camera_input(label = "Take a pic of you to be sketched out")
        
if file_image:
    input_img = Image.open(file_image)
    final_sketch = pencilsketch(np.array(input_img))
    st.write("**Output Pencil Sketch**")
    st.image(final_sketch, use_column_width=True)
    download_image("final_image.jpeg")
    email_box("hello")

else:
    st.write("You haven't uploaded any image file")
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: I know the content of the text is not same manually is it possible to increase the size of the button @Jamin Shaibu

Comment: Ah yeah, my  main focus was on the `download button`. You can add `padding-left: 5px;`, `padding-right: 5px` in the first  `div.stButton >` Just play around with the `px` to see which one works best for you.

Comment: i have tried the same with columns method to move the submit button into center but its not working any idea on this

Comment: Yeah I did tried it too  but I got to realize that, it is because that specific `button` is in the `form widget` that is why, but the `column` approach should work fine with both the `st.button` and the `st.download_button`.

Comment: Instead of form if i create manually(check box with button ) it will work right @Jamiu shaibu

Comment: Yeah that is why the `st.download_button` was able to work with the `st.columns()`, You can see that the `st.download_button` is outside of the `form widget`. It works in the `checkbox`, yes.

Comment: While inspecting i have found something which can move the submit button into center