# Why does my streamlit app reset on using the radio button?

Tags: python, streamlit

So I have a sidebar. When "Go" in the sidebar is selected, the main dashboard should update. This works.

What doesn't work is when the radio button (marketing consent) within the main dashboard is selected, the entire dashboard resets. It will revert to the original view as opposed to what it looked like after "Go" was selected. It's as if the "Go" button resets and gets unselected, when the radio button is clicked...

```
"""
# My first app
Here's our first attempt at using data to create a table:
"""

##Packages
from unicodedata import numeric
import streamlit as st
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
import pandasql as ps
import altair as alt
import plotly.express as px


st.set_page_config(page_title = "Dashboard")
st.title("Dashboard ")


##Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'first': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'second': [10, 20, 30, 40],
    'third': ['apple', 'banana', 'grape', 'grape'],
    'fourth': ['walter', 'skyler', 'hank', 'marie']

    })

####
###Sidebar things
####

###Logo
with st.sidebar.container():

st.sidebar.title("Sidebar")


with st.sidebar.container():
    add_selectbox = st.sidebar.multiselect(
        'Choose some properties',
        (df.third.unique())
    )

    fourth_box = st.sidebar.selectbox(
        'Choose your country',
        (df.fourth.unique()),
        index = 1
    )



####Page 1
if st.sidebar.button('Go!'):

    with st.container():

        status  = st.radio(
            "Marketing Consent Status",
            ('Yes', 'All'))
       

        df_iris = px.data.iris()
 

        if marketing_status == 'Yes':
           fig_1 = px.bar(df_iris, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="species",
                   hover_data=['petal_width'], barmode = 'stack')

            st.plotly_chart(fig_1, use_container_width=True)
        
        elif marketing_status == 'All':
            st.write('Hello, *World!')


else:

    with st.container():

        df_map = px.data.gapminder().query("year==2007")
        fig_map = px.choropleth(df_map, locations="iso_alpha",
                    color="lifeExp", # lifeExp is a column of gapminder
                    hover_name="country", # column to add to hover information
                    color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Plasma)

        st.plotly_chart(fig_map, use_container_width=True)
```

As you'll see, when you use the radio button (Marketing Consent Button) after it appears , it will revert to the map view of the main.

Comment: Does this answer your question?[user input is not capturing the text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73354348/19290081)

Answer (score 0):

To prevent widget interactions from causing the entire app to rerun, you can make your widgets part of a [form](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/control-flow/st.form) with a submit button, e.g.:

```
with st.form("my_form"):
    st.write("Inside the form")
    slider_val = st.slider("Form slider")
    checkbox_val = st.checkbox("Form checkbox")

    # Every form must have a submit button.
    submitted = st.form_submit_button("Submit")
    if submitted:
        st.write("slider", slider_val, "checkbox", checkbox_val)

st.write("Outside the form")
```